# PhpStorm doesn't treat '$' and 'jQuery' equally

Tags: jquery, phpstorm

PhpStorm doesn't recognize several functions when used with '$' instead of 'jQuery'. I have added jQuery to Libraries and then I have invalidated Caches and restarted the app.

jQuery version: 3.3.1

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Warning: Method is not of Function type.

```
jQuery(window).scrollTop();
```

This code has no warnings.

Comment: Is this a wordpress app? Wordpress use jQuery.noConflict which removes `$` alias

Comment: No, I don't use any CMS.

Comment: So is this a code linting error or execution error?

Comment: It's just a warning.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"doesn't recognize"*? They don't work?

Comment: Need more details about which js linter is used and how it is configured. The docs for that linter should help you

Comment: It doesn't understand that several functions are part of the jQuery library. ScrollTop is also used in vanilla JS and it has priority unless I write 'jQuery' instead of '$' in that case it looks for ScrollTop in jQuery.

Comment: I didn't modify used linters. Is there a way to find out which is used defaultly?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding JQuery typings (either via **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries**, **Download...** or by running `npm i @types/jquery` in project dir) - this should solve the issue